# Realizar premutación y etiquetarla

Tags: python

Imaginemos que tengo un vector o una lista con los siguientes elementos:

```
v = ['coche', 'casa', 'arbol', 'moto']
```

Quiero sacar de ahí todas las permutaciones posibles que hay, y además asignarles una etiqueta.

Es decir, si por ejemplo me saca la permutación:

```
v = ['moto', 'coche', 'arbol', 'casa']
```

Pues que esa sea la permutación 1, y que el algoritmo sepa que siempre que obtengo esa permutación es la 1.

La parte de permutar se podria hacer con el módulo `itertools` si no me equivoco, pero me pierdo a la hora de intentar etiquetar cada permutación ¿Cómo podría hacerlo?

Comment: Bienvenidx a Stack Overflow en español. 
Las preguntas del tipo: "Tengo que hacer esto" sin mostrar el código que has escrito no suelen ser bien recibidas ya que la respuesta será siempre adivinando y no encaja en el formato de preguntas y respuestas del sitio. 
Recomiendo que hagas el [recorrido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) para entender el funcionamiento de SO y ya de paso ganar tu primera medalla. 
Por otro lado, estaría bien que le echaras un vistazo a [Cómo preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) para que tus preguntas reciban respuesta cuanto antes.

Answer (score 3):

Se me ocurre que lo puedes meter a un diccionario.

Ejemplo usando Python 3:

```
>>> import itertools
>>> v = ['coche', 'casa', 'arbol', 'moto']
>>> perms = list(itertools.permutations(v))
>>> perms # Todas las permutaciones
[('coche', 'casa', 'arbol', 'moto'), ('coche', 'casa', 'moto', 'arbol'), ('coche', 'arbol', 'casa', 'moto'), ('coche', 'arbol', 'moto', 'casa'), ('coche', 'moto', 'casa', 'arbol'), ('coche', 'moto', 'arbol', 'casa'), ('casa', 'coche', 'arbol', 'moto'), ('casa', 'coche', 'moto', 'arbol'), ('casa', 'arbol', 'coche', 'moto'), ('casa', 'arbol', 'moto', 'coche'), ('casa', 'moto', 'coche', 'arbol'), ('casa', 'moto', 'arbol', 'coche'), ('arbol', 'coche', 'casa', 'moto'), ('arbol', 'coche', 'moto', 'casa'), ('arbol', 'casa', 'coche', 'moto'), ('arbol', 'casa', 'moto', 'coche'), ('arbol', 'moto', 'coche', 'casa'), ('arbol', 'moto', 'casa', 'coche'), ('moto', 'coche', 'casa', 'arbol'), ('moto', 'coche', 'arbol', 'casa'), ('moto', 'casa', 'coche', 'arbol'), ('moto', 'casa', 'arbol', 'coche'), ('moto', 'arbol', 'coche', 'casa'), ('moto', 'arbol', 'casa', 'coche')]
>>> tags = dict(zip(range(len(perms)), perms))
>>> tags # Cada permutación con un tag (o ID)
{0: ('coche', 'casa', 'arbol', 'moto'), 1: ('coche', 'casa', 'moto', 'arbol'), 2: ('coche', 'arbol', 'casa', 'moto'), 3: ('coche', 'arbol', 'moto', 'casa'), 4: ('coche', 'moto', 'casa', 'arbol'), 5: ('coche', 'moto', 'arbol', 'casa'), 6: ('casa', 'coche', 'arbol', 'moto'), 7: ('casa', 'coche', 'moto', 'arbol'), 8: ('casa', 'arbol', 'coche', 'moto'), 9: ('casa', 'arbol', 'moto', 'coche'), 10: ('casa', 'moto', 'coche', 'arbol'), 11: ('casa', 'moto', 'arbol', 'coche'), 12: ('arbol', 'coche', 'casa', 'moto'), 13: ('arbol', 'coche', 'moto', 'casa'), 14: ('arbol', 'casa', 'coche', 'moto'), 15: ('arbol', 'casa', 'moto', 'coche'), 16: ('arbol', 'moto', 'coche', 'casa'), 17: ('arbol', 'moto', 'casa', 'coche'), 18: ('moto', 'coche', 'casa', 'arbol'), 19: ('moto', 'coche', 'arbol', 'casa'), 20: ('moto', 'casa', 'coche', 'arbol'), 21: ('moto', 'casa', 'arbol', 'coche'), 22: ('moto', 'arbol', 'coche', 'casa'), 23: ('moto', 'arbol', 'casa', 'coche')}
```

Claro que también lo puedes hacer al revés para que cada permutación sea la llave y el ID sea el valor:

```
>>> tags = dict(zip(perms, range(len(perms))))
>>> tags
{('coche', 'casa', 'arbol', 'moto'): 0, ('coche', 'casa', 'moto', 'arbol'): 1, ('coche', 'arbol', 'casa', 'moto'): 2, ('coche', 'arbol', 'moto', 'casa'): 3, ('coche', 'moto', 'casa', 'arbol'): 4, ('coche', 'moto', 'arbol', 'casa'): 5, ('casa', 'coche', 'arbol', 'moto'): 6, ('casa', 'coche', 'moto', 'arbol'): 7, ('casa', 'arbol', 'coche', 'moto'): 8, ('casa', 'arbol', 'moto', 'coche'): 9, ('casa', 'moto', 'coche', 'arbol'): 10, ('casa', 'moto', 'arbol', 'coche'): 11, ('arbol', 'coche', 'casa', 'moto'): 12, ('arbol', 'coche', 'moto', 'casa'): 13, ('arbol', 'casa', 'coche', 'moto'): 14, ('arbol', 'casa', 'moto', 'coche'): 15, ('arbol', 'moto', 'coche', 'casa'): 16, ('arbol', 'moto', 'casa', 'coche'): 17, ('moto', 'coche', 'casa', 'arbol'): 18, ('moto', 'coche', 'arbol', 'casa'): 19, ('moto', 'casa', 'coche', 'arbol'): 20, ('moto', 'casa', 'arbol', 'coche'): 21, ('moto', 'arbol', 'coche', 'casa'): 22, ('moto', 'arbol', 'casa', 'coche'): 23}
```

Entonces, si quieres obtener el tag o ID de una permutación, simplemente haces:

```
>>> permutacion = ('moto', 'arbol', 'coche', 'casa')
>>> tags.get(permutacion)
22
>>> permutacion = ('esta', 'permutacion', 'no', 'existe')
>>> tags.get(permutacion)
None
```

Puedes usar cualquier tipo de ID, por ejemplo con UUID:

```
>>> import uuid
>>> ids = [str(uuid.uuid4()) for _ in perms]
>>> tags = dict(zip(perms, ids))
>>> tags
{('coche', 'casa', 'arbol', 'moto'): '1e0dfbc9-ded0-4041-ba66-f621e47768e0', ('coche', 'casa', 'moto', 'arbol'): '404b47e0-2f1b-4450-a756-760185a6941e', ('coche', 'arbol', 'casa', 'moto'): 'b81dfd15-91ae-419c-bf27-063b5b0fb228', ('coche', 'arbol', 'moto', 'casa'): 'f3eeca60-cfa0-4a09-a530-d4a803e3c490', ('coche', 'moto', 'casa', 'arbol'): 'dd230295-9a8c-4ba4-8d79-3c63f17d36e4', ('coche', 'moto', 'arbol', 'casa'): 'ad39b5a3-43a0-43ba-80c5-c5d6577c884d', ('casa', 'coche', 'arbol', 'moto'): 'c77f4fb3-3007-4e43-9867-feecc5ca8b92', ('casa', 'coche', 'moto', 'arbol'): '12f6cb92-adb0-4253-bc16-c7225794b5ea', ('casa', 'arbol', 'coche', 'moto'): '8bf80606-68fb-48b0-9b11-18cba368c550', ('casa', 'arbol', 'moto', 'coche'): 'f0085932-cda3-425a-9ddc-2179c0be5c09', ('casa', 'moto', 'coche', 'arbol'): 'a115cd50-80df-47f8-8431-b6828b3f71fa', ('casa', 'moto', 'arbol', 'coche'): '423c58d9-b580-44c5-9581-046fce065b64', ('arbol', 'coche', 'casa', 'moto'): '5b4ce977-6b81-43e7-ab69-a53fcb74ccf2', ('arbol', 'coche', 'moto', 'casa'): 'db0acd18-12b7-4a94-9cc2-7c245eec02e2', ('arbol', 'casa', 'coche', 'moto'): 'c1962ccf-73ef-4e16-9be2-09a522dfd8d0', ('arbol', 'casa', 'moto', 'coche'): 'c318bf3a-78b0-4cac-a04b-43fba87eb2d1', ('arbol', 'moto', 'coche', 'casa'): '6b824a49-1903-4ef3-b860-cca8b4be1417', ('arbol', 'moto', 'casa', 'coche'): '6d420759-a0f8-40b3-9cd5-c61a827ed578', ('moto', 'coche', 'casa', 'arbol'): '6eb8c29d-6529-48a9-aa19-9a613c929136', ('moto', 'coche', 'arbol', 'casa'): 'de741d8c-5f2a-4b17-92d0-2092d11a8876', ('moto', 'casa', 'coche', 'arbol'): 'ff50e750-4670-48b2-89da-25a56a59de63', ('moto', 'casa', 'arbol', 'coche'): 'ce344481-0783-4322-87ec-ba104528ff05', ('moto', 'arbol', 'coche', 'casa'): '290ce111-0051-4bd0-85f0-003f5cb31292', ('moto', 'arbol', 'casa', 'coche'): 'b061db44-f8a7-461b-b39d-0044e770e4a0'}
>>> permutacion = ('moto', 'arbol', 'coche', 'casa')
>>> tags.get(permutacion)
'290ce111-0051-4bd0-85f0-003f5cb31292'
```